# How to Show last period (Fiscal Year) of sale, based on multi-filters report

Tags: powerbi, dax

I tried create a dashboard based on fiscal year, with more  Filters, like region, sales rep name, ...

Example files avaliable on dropbox:

https://www.dropbox.com/sh/l25kdz6enmg35yb/AABPuOk3kKOpfQdKDfRUcnX2a?dl=0

On my closest attempt, i tried this follow:

Add one column on my data set, naming each period as distinct number, like: "17";"18";"19", due to deslocated fiscal year (april to march).

Then create a measure:

```
PREVIOUS CROP_YEAR = SWITCH(TRUE();
SELECTEDVALUE('dataset'[Crop-X])=16;(CALCULATE(SUM('dataset'[Order Value]);ALL('dataset')));
SELECTEDVALUE('dataset'[Crop-X])=17;(CALCULATE(SUM('dataset'[Order Value]);ALL('dataset')));
SELECTEDVALUE('dataset'[Crop-X])=18;(CALCULATE(SUM('dataset'[Order Value]);ALL('dataset')));
SELECTEDVALUE('dataset'[Crop-X])=19;(CALCULATE(SUM('dataset'[Order Value]);ALL('dataset')));
0)
```

Expected output was:
Values based on all filters applied, But instead i just get an empty charts

Comment: Thanks on advance

Answer (score 1):

The measure is return the total because you are explicitly asking for it by using the ALL function. This removes all the filters from the dataset thus returning a grand total. This can work but it creates a complexity in your dataset with respect of having two time dimensions. The way to solve this is to first make sure you filter the date correctly with respect to both dimensions

```
PREVIOUS YEAR = 
    CALCULATE(
        SUM('dataset'[Order Value]);
        FILTER( 
            ALL ( 'dataset' ) ;
            AND ( 
                'dataset'[Crop-X] = MAX('dataset'[Crop-X]) -1 ;
                'dataset'[YEAR] = MAX('dataset'[YEAR] ) -1
            )
        )
    )
```

Furthermore, this measure still uses the ALL function which means any other filters get ignored. Using ALLSELECTED instead would result in the relative time filtering to result in nothing as soon as you select any time based slicer in your dashboard, this prevents the filter from looking at any other part of the dataset that is not within the primary sliced dataset. The workaround would be to use ALLEXCEPT and add the filters you want to be able to use as arguments. Downside is that any filter you add to your dashboard will have to be added to the exception manually.

```
PREVIOUS YEAR = 
    CALCULATE(
        SUM('dataset'[Order Value]);
        FILTER( 
            ALLEXCEPT( 'dataset' ; Dim1[Group] ; Dim1[Manager] ; Dim1[Region] ) ;
            AND ( 
                'dataset'[Crop-X] = MAX('dataset'[Crop-X]) -1 ;
                'dataset'[YEAR] = MAX('dataset'[YEAR] ) -1
            )
        )
    )
```

Comment: Hello, i tried second option, without calendar table, but do not returns same period based on filter selection, see:

" PREVIOUS CROP YEAR = 
    CALCULATE(
        SUM('dataset'[Order Value]);
        FILTER(ALL('dataset'); 'dataset'[Date] = EDATE(min('dataset'[Date]);-12))
) "   , I made anoter tentative without "MIN", but with no results,  i think if you can open my file, will be better to locate which part is inconsistent..

Comment: I've tried it on your PowerBI and got it to work, but I still don't understand what you are trying to do exactly. I've added two tables which are not affected by your time filters on the left and added a measure to your first table that respects both the real year and the crop year filters, that is what you are after? Also, convert the [Crop-X] column to a value and to make sure that both the order total and the previous year measure are in the same table. [link](https://filetransfer.kpn.com/download/825bc40b-2b51-4f17-a946-c9a34efe6444#WBnvHAGa3SnNuzujyKpfX8oIejJJooR5QGy1adrlQOM)

Comment: Also see update in my answer for more explanation  on the use of ALL, ALLSELECTED and ALLEXCEPT. In your dashboard example I've used ALL, but I'd recommend using the ALLEXCEPT to make sure the other slicers on your dashboard keep working

Comment: Hi Jelle, when I use Allexcept work fine with my slicers, thank you

Comment: But one of sliders are columns set as numbers,for visual request from business, 1 to 12, represent each month,  and this  way, even using Allexcept , or a calendartable with parallel period , still messed up

Comment: I will post this way to illustrate Better