# How to do make a coherent IF statement using time in and time out filtered by a key in DAX

Tags: powerbi

I am trying to find out where employees are starting a new call type on the same day at the same store before they finish the previous call type using DAX in my Power BI report.

Each employee is supposed to start a Health or HyHo call and finish it before they start another call. By "toggling" they are throwing off our time split calculation and exaggerating the hours spent in store vs the payroll hours. I have a key which is the employee number, visit date and store ID that I am trying to use to filter this. I've tried an IF statement Using Visit Time Out is less than Visit Time In filtered by the key. Earliest and Earlier aren't working for the In/Out time nor does MIN or Max.

The result would be a simple text statement "Toggling?"
[Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pyjw0.png)

Comment: Please give us your data and attempt you have done so far.

Comment: An avenue you could explore is how to change context within your calculations using a combination of [CALCULTE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/calculate-function-dax) and derivatives of [ALL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/all-function-dax). Or have a look at some posts around the community [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57183670/how-to-show-last-period-fiscal-year-of-sale-based-on-multi-filters-report/) [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57401841/create-measure-to-calculate-value-based-on-lookup-by-date)